# Determine the truth value of the following sentence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi all I need help for the proper way to justify my answer. I saw people using negation before but do not really understand how it work.

Given sets $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{1,2,4\}$, and $P(y,z)$ denotes $5|(y+z)$, determine the truth value of  $\forall y \in A, \exists z \in B \colon P(y,z)$.

My thoughts:
$\forall y \in A$: $y$ can be any of the number in set $A$.
$\exists z \in B$: I can pick one number in set $B$ that will satisfy the relation $P(y,z)$. I can interpret that $5$ cannot divide $(1 + 1)$, $5$ cannot divide $(2 + 1)$, $5$ cannot divide $(3 + 1)$, $5$ cannot divide $(1 + 2)$, $5$ cannot divide $(2 + 2)$, $5$ cannot divide $(3 + 2)$, $5$ divide $(1 + 4)$, $5$ cannot divide $(2 + 4)$, $5$ cannot divide $(3 + 4)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Let $y=1$. Note that if we pick $z=4$, then $5\mid y+z$. Let $y=2$. Does $5$ divide $2+1$? Continue.

Comment: $|$ is 'divides'?

Comment: negation means **not**.

Answer (score 0):

Because the small cardinal sets $A$, $B$ you could simply use brute force to check all possibilities of $P(y,z)$.

Comment: Also I might suggest reading about universal and existential quantifiers, and their negations. The proving the negation of your statement would suffice. In doing so you need to negate the quantifiers, or show there exists a $y$ such that for all $z$ $P$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false. Here's why:

Take $y = 2 \in A$. Then for all $z \in B$ we have $5 \not \mid (y+z)$. In fact, $z$ has to be $1$, $2$ and $4$, but $5 \not \mid (2+1)$, $5 \not \mid (2+2)$ and $5 \not \mid (2+4)$.

Comment: Hi Stefan, for the justification all I need is to find a y that make the whole statement false? Sometimes I get confuse, do I fixed the y first and then use z to test it?

Comment: If the statement were true, then for $y = 2$ there would exist some $z \in B$ such that $5 \mid (2+z)$. Since there is no such $z \in B$, this statement is false. Don't worry - these things can be very confusing at first.